# Postman - String match resulting in assertion error

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I am trying to validate a JSON response with data from csv file.
Both contain same values but still test fails.

Here is the error on collection runner
Address Line 1 Validation 0 | AssertionError: expected '9 DRAGSTAFF AVE' to equal '9 DRAGSTAFF AVE'

Comment: Please paste your code and the csv file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thats usually formating error , just copy paste the actual part from the assertion message and replace the expected value in csv .

[image]

copy the highlighted part and replace the value in csv ( hope your assertion is like pm.expect(responsefromjson).to.equal(valuefrmcsv)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It worked.

Comment: Could you accept by clicking the tick sign

Comment: I am getting similar error and tried what was suggested above but does not work for this case  - Full Name Validation 2 | AssertionError: expected 'ARDEHASO LIBDISPLAY' to deeply equal 'ARDEHASO LIBDISPLAY'

Comment: assertion is like pm.expect(valuefromcsv).to.equal(jsonresponse)

Comment: . Please note - name has lots of spaces in between which is not see in the error message.

Comment: Can you add the json to question